# Setup USB Printing Ubuntu 14.04 on Crouton Toshiba Chromebook 2

Tags: drivers, printing, cups-lpd

I have an installation of Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity installed by Crouton on a Toshiba Chromebook 2. I would like to know how to setup USB printing, as no forum post or Google search helped me solve the problem. I am trying to connect an HP Deskjet 952c printer.

I tried installing the HPLIP, but the installation kept giving me an error about CUPS.
I tried starting CUPS but it said it couldn't start, or it doesn't exist. I tried installing every package imaginable, I tried going through config file hell, and editing files, and confs, but nothing ever works.

So I need an expert to help me setup this stupid printer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in System Settings -> Printers to configure a printer.

I originally configured my Printers using HPLIP, but it took a very long time.

I was absolutely annoyed with myself when I found this feature as it only took a few seconds maybe a minute to configure itself.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried. When I go there, I get this message saying that the printer service is not enabled. How do I enable it?

http://i.imgur.com/Kgkw8LO.png

Comment: @Polygon6789. Have a look at this [forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1778698)